# Getting list of objects from a folder ina main bucket in S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I used to get the list of objects from my S3 bucket using S3Service.listObjects (jets3 classes) in talend. Now  I have the files inside a folder in that bucket. Now when I use  Bucket/folder path in the S3Service.lostObjects function, it gives the error "Failed to parse XML document with handler class org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler".

How to get the list of objects from a folder inside the main bucket in S3??

Please Help.

Comment: I aslo tried using a prifix with listObjects i.e listObjects("Bucketname", "/foldername/") but then the error message "The method listObjects(string,string) is not defined for the type S3Service".